# How to type hint a type with bool return values from any rich comparison?

Tags: python, type-hinting

How to type hint a type with `bool` return values from any rich comparison?

For example, using `Any` just doesn't work (`a` and `b` are also not constrained):

```py
from typing import Any

def f(a: Any, b: Any) -> bool:
    return a < b

# main.py:4: error: Returning Any from function declared to return "bool"  [no-any-return]
```

Using `TypeVar` also doesn't (although they are now constrained to be the same type, they don't even necessarily have to support comparison):

```py
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")

def f(a: T, b: T) -> bool:
    return a < b

# main.py:6: error: Returning Any from function declared to return "bool"  [no-any-return]
# main.py:6: error: Unsupported left operand type for < ("T")  [operator]
```

My examples shown are only for `__lt__`, but is there a way to type hint any two fully comparable objects (of the same type and returns `bool` values)? If not, are there anything similar or related that can be achieved?